# What does int(str(plots[len(y)][0])[0]) do while creating a boxplot?

Tags: python, function, plot

What is this code doing:

```
plots = {1:[111], 2:[121,122], 3:[131,132,133], 4:[221,222,223,224], 5:[231,232,233,234,235], 6:[231,232,233,234,235,236]}
def boxplot(x,y,df):
    rows = int(str(plots[len(y)][0])[0])
    columns = int(str(plots[len(y)][0])[1])
    plt.figure(figsize=(7*columns,7*rows))
```

Comment: Which part of the expression are you asking about?

Comment: Entire part. I am learning python. Why is "plots=..." required? Also, in 'rows = int(str(plots[len(y)][0])[0])' why are we calculating len(y), converting that to str and then again to int

Comment: `plots` are data to be plotted `rows` and `cols` are calculated by `plots` and some others parameters from `boxplot()`

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down to multiple instructions:

```
int(str(plots[len(y)][0])[0])

        plots[len(y)]          # the len(y)th plot
                     [0]       # the 0th element of that plot (presumably, an integer)
    str(                )      # converted to a string
                         [0]   # the 0th element of the string (i.e. first character)
int(                        )  # converted back to an int
```

tl;dr it's a quick way to find the first digit of `plots[len(y)][0]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! What is this code doing: "plots = {1:[111], 2:[121,122], 3:[131,132,133], 4:[221,222,223,224], 5:[231,232,233,234,235], 6:[231,232,233,234,235,236]}"

Comment: Also, using "plots = {1:[111], 2:[121,122], 3:[131,132,133]}" is giving me the same plot without errors.

Comment: it's creating a dictionary with integers as keys and lists of integers as values, and assigning it to the variable name "plots"